# How to convert a SOLR mutivalued field into equivalent elastic search field

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

I'm working towards converting a solr schema file into elastic search equivalent.

I do not know how to convert a field that is multivalued in SOLR to elastic search equivalent

for example :

```
<field name="projectid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

i looked at elasticsearch multi-field option but it looks more like a copyfield option.

Is all the fields in elasticsearch inherently multivalued.

please can you help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elasticsearch equivalent is an [array type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-array-type.html). You just need to create an array in your JSON document and Elasticsearch will automatically detect it is an array. A simple example would be:

```
{
   "name":"arrayExample",
   "tags":["one", "two", "three" ]
}
```

If you were to do a search on the `tags` field with the search term `one` the above document would be returned.